# ASP.NET Core 6, Angular & REST prefix (using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

How do I get an ASP.NET Core 6 Angular app working with a prefix on the API routes?

I create a brand new project using the `ASP.NET Core with Angular` template. I then make two small changes:

1. Change the Angular component to use the `api/` prefix:

[image]

2. Change the WebApi controller to use the `api/` prefix:

[image]

The result is a 404:

[image]

Comment: I've also tried this, it doesn't help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343735/asp-net-core-3-adding-route-prefix

Comment: Also tried using `UsePathBase` - no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72112184/214980

Comment: Can you share your ```baseUrl``` string in angular app?

Comment: You've changed something else you are not showing. I just spun up a new project in VS 2022, made the 2 changes you you've shown and the API hit works just fine.

Comment: @mxmissile here's a video of me doing just those two steps: https://www.veed.io/view/cef222fa-2cb4-4f3e-bf10-dd4df52cd899

Comment: What happens if you hit /api/weatherforecast in your browser?

Comment: It redirects to the angular app home page.

Comment: AFAIK, normally I will create both Angular app and Web API in different projects. So both projects will use different host domain (in local development, using the localhost with different ports). And also you need to implement CORS in Web API so your Angular App is able to send the request to Web API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### EXPLANATION:

This behaviour is happening because of the change in ASP.NET Core to have the front-end dev server proxy requests to ASP.NET Core, rather than the other way round (which was the approach in previous versions of ASP.NET Core). In other words, the Angular dev server proxies requests to ASP.NET Core for (eg) API data, whereas in previous ASP.NET versions, IIS Express would have proxied Angular requests to the Angular SPA server.

See:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-4/#improved-single-page-app-spa-templates

### SOLUTION:

In the `ClientApp` folder, there is now a `proxy.conf.js` file. Adding the `api/` prefix into this file means that the Angular SPA dev server is now aware that requests to that prefixed URL should pass through to the .NET server:

[image: configuring bypass for the SPA proxy server]

You can use wildcards like `"/api/**"`

### USEFUL TO KNOW:

As this may be useful for related issues, without the prefix in the `proxy.conf.js` file, the actual response to the HTTP request is as shown:

[image: SPA proxy response]

This is not a response from the ASP.NET Core code; this is the response from Angular - i.e. that request is not passing through the Angular proxy server to IIS Express.

Additionally, it's useful to know that the SPA proxy server gets launched using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy` package. I had changed my `Program.cs` startup code entirely to remove the Angular/SPA logic, but I was still getting the SPA Proxy server on startup, and the same response code from the API route. This is because in the `launchsettings.json`, there are these references to the `SpaProxy` package:

[image: launch config of the SPA proxy server]

So unless you remove those two references in the `launchSettings.json` file, the SPA proxy will continue to launch. If you want to completely remove the Spa Proxy, remove these references. Then you can debug what is happening without the SPA Proxy involved, if you need to. However, if you want to continue with the new `SPA proxy to ASP.NET Core` approach, the `proxy.conf.js` file seems to be the way forward.